Computing the factorial of a number in ARM assembly
I'm new to ARM assembly, and I want to improve myself.
Here is code that I wrote. It computes and returns the factorial of the integer passed in r0. Any suggestion to improve it? Any tip to improve my skills in assembly in general?
.global factorial

factorial:
  cmp r0, #2
  ble less_than_or_equal_to_2

resume:
  mov r1, r0

loop:
  sub r1, r1, #1
  mul r0, r0, r1
  cmp r1, #2
  bgt loop
  bx  lr

less_than_or_equal_to_2:
  cmp r0, #0
  ble less_than_or_equal_to_zero
  bx  lr

less_than_or_equal_to_zero:
  mov r0, #1
  bx  lr



Your code can be simplified down to this:
factorial:
    movs r1, r0         @ accumulator = argument, set condition flags
    bgt 2f              @ jump to middle of loop (no multiply on first number)
    movs r0, #1
    bx lr               @ if argument <= 0, return #1
1:  muls r0, r0, r1
2:  subs r1, r1, #1     @ decrement argument, set flags
    bgt 1b              @ loop while argument > 0
    bx lr

You seem to be unaware that most arithmetic operations implicitly set the condition flags based on the result of the computation. An explicit cmp instruction is rarely needed. In classic ARM, instructions come in two flavors: subs sets the condition flags and sub doesn't, same for muls versus mul and so on. If you append an s, you get the variant that sets flags. If you target Thumb, you only have the flag-setting variant available. Deleting the cmp instruction cuts down your loop from four to three instructions. Using movs in the initialization code instead of cmp also saves an instruction.
I rearranged the loop body so that decrement is the last instruction before the backjump, which is the typical arrangement. In your case, you could have used mul and subs and placed them in any order because mul doesn't clobber the flags. I went with muls and subs so that my code would run on ARM and Thumb, and then I had to put subs last. To preserve the original execution order, my initialization code jumps into the middle of the loop. The first instruction to execute is still decrement. This is another common theme in assembly programming.
I used local labels. These are numeric labels (like 1 or 2) and they are allowed to appear multiple times in the same program, which is nice. A label like loop quickly becomes problematic because it can appear only once, but you have hundreds of loops in any real-world program. With local labels, the ambiguity is resolved by appending the letters f or b for a forward or backward jump respectively. The jump then targets the first occurrence of that label in the specified direction.
